# How to post on stumble upon using api?

Tags: social-media, stumbleupon

I want to post on stumbleupon using api . I have search a lot of but not got any satisfy answer . I want to promote my website  on stumbleupon using api . So please help me how can it is possible . Because i have seen many tools which provides this type service . So can any guide me how can i post link on stumbleupon using api or other way .

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same thing and google turned up this, which looks like it has been around for a while and is the only solution for it.

http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/business-tools/supr/supr-api